# In Ruby on Rails how can I dynamically refresh a global variable in the html without reloading the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use a global variable in ruby to show its value on my home page in html tag. I want to increase the value of this variable dynamically on the screen every time I press a button( which sends a get request to one of my endpoints). The problem is the value only changes when i reload the button not on the button press. I don't want to reload my page every time as it messes with my other stuff. Is there a way?

I added the variable with $ prefix but the button pressing wont change its value. Only if I reload the page the value of the variable is increased by the amount of times i pressed it.

This is the controller for home

```
class PagesController < ActionController::Base
  def home
    $sum
  end
end
```

Controller for the get endpoint. I increase sum in the get_colors method.

```
class ColorController < ActionController::Base
  include ControllerHelper

  def show
    $sum = 0
    current_number = params[:number]
    get_colors(current_number)
  end
end
```

HTML:

```
<td><%= $sum %></td>
```

I'm not sure if its possible what I ask, as I just started using ruby.

Comment: You need to understand the fundamental difference between client side and server side programming. Your global variable only exists on the server until the page is sent to the client and the user interacting with the page occurs on the client. https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/serverless/glossary/client-side-vs-server-side/

Answer (score 2):

Once the page is rendered, it's static. If you want to change the value you have to make a ajax request when you click the button and make response to change this. Another option for you is ActionCable.